Model specification - time series. Estimation of the effect of human capital on growth
Thank you for your help in advance !
I'm working on a research project at undergraduate level on the effect of human capital on growth in Nigeria from 1980 to 2018.
My current model specification is :
ln(RGDP)=ln(K)+ln(L)+ln(secondary)+ln(primary)+ln(TFP)+epsilon
where K : total capital formation

L : working age labor force
secondary : enrollment rate in secondary education
primary : enrollment rate in primary education
TFP: total factor productivity -> wanted to use this as a proxy for technology

Also - augmented dicker fuller test :

log(K) is not stationnary (p value=0,54)
log(L) is not stationnary (p value=0,67)
log(secondary) is not stationnary (p value=0,25)
log(primary) is not stationnary (p value=0,15)
log(TFP) is not stationnary (p value=0,55)

The results of the regression are okay

3 stars : log(K), log(TFP)
2 stars : log(primary), log(secondary)
1 star : intercept
Other variables : log(labor), p value of 0,46

BUT the VIF is quite high for log(K) : 13 and log(L) : 20
I also tested the residuals, which "are" (we can't reject) normally distributed
And there seems to be no autocorrelation between the residual (D-W statistics=1,86 ; p value=0,25)
Thus my questions are :

Is it a good specification ? How can I improve it, if not ?
How to reduce the VIF ?
Should I differentiate the variables (and which variables) to have stationnary time series ?
Should I lag the variables ?
Why is the coefficient of "primary" negative, when we can expect a positive one ?

Thank you very much for your future answers, I wish you a great day !
